# Exception in RavenDB when doing bulk inserts

Tags: ravendb

I'm doing some bulk inserts with RavenDB, and at some random document I get an `InvalidOperationException` with a HTTP 403 (forbidden), and the message "This single use token has expired".

The code is pretty straightforward:

```
using (var bulkInsert = store.BulkInsert("MyDatabase", new BulkInsertOptions { CheckForUpdates = true, BatchSize = 512 })
{
    // Mapping stuff
    bulkInsert.store(doc, productId);
}
```

I have tried experimenting with the batch size without any luck.

How do I fix it?

I'm using RavenDB 2.5 build 2700 and hosting RavenDb as a Windows service.

When running RavenDB in a console, I can see that it logs this message:

> Error when using events transport. An operation was attempted on a
>   nonexistent network connection.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using both client & server at version 2700?

Comment: Yes - I just double checked.

Comment: Is your `IDocumentStore` a single instance, or are multiple threads creating new instances?

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz It's a singleton.